# I2Cdetect doesnt detect my I2C device

Tags: i2c, sensor, battery

I am using a BQ27441EVM-G1B. It is a TI battery fuel gauge board, that is used to measure the battery voltage, current and charge left etc. Datasheet - http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq27441-g1.pdf on page no. 13, gives details about the I2C communication interface. Image attached. [image]

It tells us that the address of the device is 0xAA for reading and 0xAB for writing, which seems outside the range of the i2cdetect table. When I try to run

```
sudo i2cdetect -y 1
```

, I get a blank table. I am sure the I2C bus is working as I had connected and used another device with address 0x6B correctly. I am also sure that the gauge is fine, since it works with an interface device - EV2400 and their proprietary software bqStudio.

I have read other posts in the forum about higher range addresses, but no solution seemed to work. One of proper connections is important, and so my connections are as under:

Gauge ----> RPi B+

VSS  ----- Pin 4 (5V)

SDA ------ Pin 3 (SDA1)

SCL ------ Pin 5 (SCL1)

VOUT ----- Pin 6 (GND)

I have also tried switching VSS from 5V to GND, but that didnt work as well. I wanted the device to be "detected" before I start writing any C code. Any ideas on debugging or some sample C code to try ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some help from peers, I was able to get i2cdetect to read the values, the correct connections are:

VSS ----- > GND     , SDA ------ > SDA1,     SCL ------> SCL1      , and that's it.

Now running sudo i2cdetect -y 1 gives the address 0x55, which is the 7-bit address for the gauge.

Some code sample would be nice though. :)